# How do I place 2 buttons in the south panel with a border?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am attempting to place these in the south, two buttons side by side, but how do I go about do so?
If I just leave them like this, but buttons are automatically placed at the top.

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");

panel1.add(button1);

JButton test2 = new JButton("Button 2");

panel1.add(button2);
```

Also, how do I put a border around the bottom panel with the two buttons inside?

Comment: what the hell is this?

Answer (score 5):

Our Frame will have two panels say topPanel, bottomPanel. TopPanel will be on the NORTH and BottomPanel will be on SOUTH.

On the main frame we use `BorderLayout` using which we will place the two panels one at NORTH and the other at SOUTH.

On BottomPanel we will use `FlowLayout` starting from center. So what ever components you add to the bottom panel their alignment will be starting from the center.

[image]

```
private void creteUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel topPnl = new JPanel();
        JPanel btnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton btnLeft = new JButton("Left");
        JButton btnRight = new JButton("Right");

        btnPnl.add(btnLeft);
        btnPnl.add(btnRight);

        btnPnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        mainPanel.add(topPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(btnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Top Panel");
        topPnl.add(label);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: When the window becomes too small, one of the buttons disappear (instead one going above the other one). What to do to avoid that behavior?

Comment: @Asqiir Please post your issue as a new question. I think we need to go through some resizing concepts. May be someone who knows better will answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set `panel2`'s layout manager to `BorderLayout`...

```
panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Add `panel1` to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position...

```
panel2.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

You can specify a `Border` for `panel1` using `setBorder`

```
pane2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details